# how to refresh view on button click with different values in iphone app

Tags: iphone, html, view

I am creating a view on viewDidLoad method it works find but when i add that same view with different x and y points on button click it does not refresh or work it shows original view which is loaded first so how to show or refresh the same view with new points.

**In my view did load**

```
int height3=(int)roundf(appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Unvaccinated);

thirdView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190,360,100,-height3)];

thirdView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(102/255.f) green:(107/255.f) 

blue:(40/255.f) alpha:1];

[self.view addSubview:thirdView];
```

**And again in button click**

```
-(IBAction)showUpdates{

int height3=(int)roundf(appDelegate.Same_Vaccination_MildEI_Unvaccinated);

thirdView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,400,100,-height3)];

thirdView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(102/255.f) 

green:(107/255.f) blue:(40/255.f) alpha:1];

[self.view addSubview:thirdView];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take 2 different objects of `UIView`. And in `viewDidLoad:` method, intializ both with it's frame. Also, add both views as subviews in `self.view`.

Now, just show first view in `viewWillAppear:` method. And when user click on button then hide first view and show second view.

Hope you have got an idea of what to do.

Cheers!

Comment: i have tried this but is there any other way not to create two views

Comment: You can create one UIView object only. And use "setFrame" method of it. And change the position of view. Hope it will help you.

Comment: can you write some code how may i do this actually i am changing only height of the frame so how to set using set frame